# Fixed range for Excel chart

Tags: charts, excel-formula, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, when selecting data for a chart, is it possible to select a range of data, that is not effected by adding or deleting columns?

Currently, my range is

```
=Agged!A1:A5,Agged!D1:F5
```

What I'm aiming for is for this range not to change if rows/columns are added or removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a named range ? You can do this by hi-lighting the range you want to use, then from the "Formulas" tab on the menu bar, choose "Create from Selection". Or, the shortcut method is hi-light the range, then type a name in the "name box" (just to the left of of the formula box)